# Can't connect my go app with docker sql base

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker, go

I hope someone can help me.
I'm trying to start my app with

```
go run main.go
```

command which should connect to the database running in Docker. I was trying to connect mysql db and postgres db from docker as well, but both have the same problem:

```
http: panic serving [::1]:62996: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 38 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
```

I can see that database running well and my tables have been created (entered through docker terminal) but my golang program cann't connect to it and i don't understand why.

I am trying to connect with the following commands:
MySQL:

```
    connStr := "root:root@tcp(localhost:3306)/mysql"
    DB, err := sql.Open("mysql", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
```

POSTGRESQL:

```
    connStr := "host=localhost port=5432 user=pqgotest password=pqgotest dbname=pqgotest sslmode=disable"
    DB, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
```

Server starts simple:

```
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/users", handlers.GetAllUsers).Methods("GET")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
```

If i make connection from db to hanlder thorugh structs and methods the app works fine with the db, but if i make through functions they cannt see each other.
command that launch mysql in docker:

```
    docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

command that launch postgres in docker:

```
docker run --name pqtestpostgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=pqgotest -e POSTGRES_DB=pqgotest -e POSTGRES_SSL=disable -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pqgotest postgres
```

I think i have some problems with networks but don't know how to fix it.

PS: i tried to change localhost to 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 but nothing happened.

Added my hanlder's function:

```
func GetAllUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    res, err := storage.UsersList()
    if err != nil {
        msg, _ := json.Marshal("Cannot retrieve from db list of users")
        w.Write(msg)
        return
    }

    var data models.ViewData
    for _, val := range res {
        data.Films = append(data.Users, val.Name)
    }

    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data)
}
```

and here the function from db

```
func UsersList() ([]models.User, error) {
    rows, err := storage.DB.Query(
        `SELECT id, name FROM users`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("couldn't receive the list of users from storage")
    }

    var users []models.User

    for rows.Next() {
        u := models.User{}
        err = rows.Scan(&u.Id, &u.Name)
        users = append(users, u)
    }

    return users, nil
}
```

Here is output of Println of the storage:

```
&sql.DB{waitDuration:0, connector:(*mysql.connector)(0xc000096008), numClosed:0x0, mu:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, freeConn:[]*sql.driverConn{(*sql.driverConn)(0xc0000c2000)}, connRe
quests:map[uint64]chan sql.connRequest{}, nextRequest:0x0, numOpen:1, openerCh:(chan struct {})(0xc0000aa000), closed:false, dep:map[sql.finalCloser]sql.depSet{(*sql.driverConn)(0xc000
0c2000):sql.depSet{(*sql.driverConn)(0xc0000c2000):true}}, lastPut:map[*sql.driverConn]string{}, maxIdleCount:0, maxOpen:0, maxLifetime:0, maxIdleTime:0, cleanerCh:(chan struct {})(nil
), waitCount:0, maxIdleClosed:0, maxIdleTimeClosed:0, maxLifetimeClosed:0, stop:(func())(0xdfea40)}
```

Structure of the project:

- main.go
- handlers
- - /handlers.go
- models
- - /models.go
- storage
- - /sql.go
- templates
- - /index.html

complete stuck trace:

```
&sql.DB{waitDuration:0, connector:(*mysql.connector)(0xc00008c008), numClosed:0x0, mu:sync.Mutex{state:0, sema:0x0}, freeConn:[]*sql.driverConn{(*sql.driverConn)(0xc0001aa090)}, connRe
quests:map[uint64]chan sql.connRequest{}, nextRequest:0x0, numOpen:1, openerCh:(chan struct {})(0xc0000aa000), closed:false, dep:map[sql.finalCloser]sql.depSet{(*sql.driverConn)(0xc000
1aa090):sql.depSet{(*sql.driverConn)(0xc0001aa090):true}}, lastPut:map[*sql.driverConn]string{}, maxIdleCount:0, maxOpen:0, maxLifetime:0, maxIdleTime:0, cleanerCh:(chan struct {})(nil
), waitCount:0, maxIdleClosed:0, maxIdleTimeClosed:0, maxLifetimeClosed:0, stop:(func())(0x107e8e0)}
2022/05/09 16:51:22 http: panic serving [::1]:61155: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 21 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0xbf
panic({0x132fec0, 0x161edb0})
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:844 +0x258
storage/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, 0x1)
        C:/go/src/user/storage/sql.go:1290 +0x53
storage/sql.(*DB).query(0x0?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0xe0?)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1732 +0x5d
storage/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0xc0000c61b0?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1710 +0xda
storage/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1728
users/storage.UsersList()
        C:/goProjects/src/users/storage/sqlDB.go:99 +0x55
users/handlers.GetAllUsers({0x141db60, 0xc0000d4000}, 0xc0000884e0?)
        C:/goProjects/src/users/handlers/handlers.go:14 +0x3b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc0000c4200?, {0x141db60?, 0xc0000d4000?}, 0x0?)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2084 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0001ce000, {0x141db60, 0xc0000d4000}, 0xc0000c4000)
        C:/goProjects/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc000088330?}, {0x141db60, 0xc0000d4000}, 0xc0000c4000)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2916 +0x43b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0001b4280, {0x141dd98, 0xc0001865a0})
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1966 +0x5d7
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:3071 +0x4db
2022/05/09 16:51:23 http: panic serving [::1]:61161: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 39 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0xbf
panic({0x132fec0, 0x161edb0})
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:844 +0x258
storage/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, 0x1)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1290 +0x53
storage/sql.(*DB).query(0x0?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0xc0?)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1732 +0x5d
storage/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0xc0000c63f0?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql/sql.go:1710 +0xda
storage/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql/sql.go:1728
users/storage.UsersList()
        C:/goProjects/src/users/storage/sqlDB.go:99 +0x55
users/handlers.GetAllUsers({0x141db60, 0xc0000d40e0}, 0xc0000886c0?)
        C:/goProjects/src/users/handlers/handlers.go:14 +0x3b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc0000c4500?, {0x141db60?, 0xc0000d40e0?}, 0x0?)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2084 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0001ce000, {0x141db60, 0xc0000d40e0}, 0xc0001e4000)
        C:/goProjects/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc000186690?}, {0x141db60, 0xc0000d40e0}, 0xc0001e4000)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2916 +0x43b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000288000, {0x141dd98, 0xc0001865a0})
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1966 +0x5d7
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:3071 +0x4db
2022/05/09 16:51:28 http: panic serving [::1]:61167: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 41 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0xbf
panic({0x132fec0, 0x161edb0})
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:844 +0x258
storage/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, 0x1)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql/sql.go:1290 +0x53
storage/sql.(*DB).query(0x0?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0xd0?)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1732 +0x5d
storage/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0xc0000c6630?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        C:/go/src/storage/sql.go:1710 +0xda
storage/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1728
users/storage.UsersList()
        C:/goProjects/src/users/storage/sqlDB.go:99 +0x55
users/handlers.GetAllUsers({0x141db60, 0xc0000d41c0}, 0xc0000888d0?)
        C:/goProjects/src/users/handlers/handlers.go:14 +0x3b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc0000c4800?, {0x141db60?, 0xc0000d41c0?}, 0x0?)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2084 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0001ce000, {0x141db60, 0xc0000d41c0}, 0xc0001e4100)
        C:/goProjects/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc000186720?}, {0x141db60, 0xc0000d41c0}, 0xc0001e4100)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2916 +0x43b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002880a0, {0x141dd98, 0xc0001865a0})
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1966 +0x5d7
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:3071 +0x4db
2022/05/09 16:51:58 http: panic serving [::1]:61204: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 7 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0xbf
panic({0x132fec0, 0x161edb0})
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:844 +0x258
storage/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, 0x1)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1290 +0x53
storage/sql.(*DB).query(0x0?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0xa0?)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql/sql.go:1732 +0x5d
storage/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0xc00014a240?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        C:/go/src/storage/sql.go:1710 +0xda
storage/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
        C:/go/src/storage/sql.go:1728
users/storage.UsersList()
        C:/goProjects/src/users/storage/sqlDB.go:99 +0x55
users/handlers.GetAllUsers({0x141db60, 0xc000150000}, 0xc00007d4a0?)
        C:/goProjects/src/users/handlers/handlers.go:14 +0x3b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00014e100?, {0x141db60?, 0xc000150000?}, 0x0?)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2084 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0001ce000, {0x141db60, 0xc000150000}, 0xc0000c4a00)
        C:/goProjects/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc000088930?}, {0x141db60, 0xc000150000}, 0xc0000c4a00)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2916 +0x43b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000068f00, {0x141dd98, 0xc0001865a0})
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1966 +0x5d7
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:3071 +0x4db
2022/05/09 16:52:58 http: panic serving [::1]:60037: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 9 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0xbf
panic({0x132fec0, 0x161edb0})
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:844 +0x258
storage/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, 0x1)
        C:/go/src/users/storage/sql.go:1290 +0x53
storage/sql.(*DB).query(0x0?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0xe0?)
        C:/go/src/storage/sql.go:1732 +0x5d
storage/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0xc00014a480?, {0x141dd28, 0xc000018098}, {0x138cbef, 0x1b}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        C:/go/src/storage/sql.go:1710 +0xda
storage/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
        C:/go/src/storage/sql/sql.go:1728
users/storage.UsersList()
        C:/goProjects/src/users/storage/sqlDB.go:99 +0x55
users/handlers.GetAllUsers({0x141db60, 0xc0001500e0}, 0xc00007d6e0?)
        C:/goProjects/src/users/handlers/handlers.go:14 +0x3b
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00014e400?, {0x141db60?, 0xc0001500e0?}, 0x0?)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2084 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0001ce000, {0x141db60, 0xc0001500e0}, 0xc0001e4200)
        C:/goProjects/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc000186780?}, {0x141db60, 0xc0001500e0}, 0xc0001e4200)
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2916 +0x43b
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000068fa0, {0x141dd98, 0xc0001865a0})
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1966 +0x5d7
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/go/src/net/http/server.go:3071 +0x4db
```

MWE:
main.go

```
package main

import (
    "users/handlers"
    "users/storage"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    connStr := "root:root@tcp(localhost:3306)/sqli"
    storage, err := storage.NewDB(connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error in main:%s\n", err)
    }

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/users", handlers.GetAllUsers).Methods("GET")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

handlers.go

```
package handlers

import (
    "users/models"
    "users/storage"
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./templates/*.html"))

func GetAllUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    res, err := storage.UsersList()
    if err != nil {
        msg, _ := json.Marshal("Cannot retrieve from db list of users")
        w.Write(msg)
        return
    }
    var data models.ViewData
    for _, val := range res {
        data.Users = append(data.Users, val.Name)
    }
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data)
}
```

storage.go

```
package storage

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
)

var DB *sql.DB

func NewDB(connStr string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    DB, err := sql.Open("mysql", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    DB.Exec(`DROP TABLE users`)
    _, err = DB.Exec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);`)
    DB.Exec("INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001", "user1")
    DB.Exec("INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002", "user2")
    return DB, nil
}

func UsersList() ([]models.User, error) {
    rows, err := DB.Query(
        `SELECT id, title FROM users`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("couldn't receive the list of users from storage")
    }
    var users []models.User
    for rows.Next() {
        f := models.User{}
        err = rows.Scan(&f.Id, &f.Name)
        films = append(films, f)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    return users, nil
}
```

models.go

```
package models

type Users struct {
    Id    string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
type ViewData struct {
    Users []string
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Users Library</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>List of users:</h1>
        <ul>
            {{range .Users}}
                <li><b>{{ . }}</b></li>
            {{end}}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know which specific line has the `nil` pointer error?  In the PostgreSQL case you're ignoring an error from connecting to the database; if you add in a check there, do things fail faster?

Comment: @DavidMaze in the postgres i have added check for this err too, but the same problem as in the MySQL. If i exclude from hanlder's function db's and make some constant string - everything works on localhost in the browser, so the problem in connection between docker and localhost.

Comment: @1oko have you pushed your code in github?

Comment: @Chandan at the moment no. But i just tried to tie up db -> handler -> router through interfaces and all works. I have problem with some connect between Docker and browser - it seems they in the different networks work.

Comment: @1oko have you tried printing before the `templateExecute` line and checked the data which is being send to template

Comment: @Chandan i have tried to remake function to func GetAllUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { var data models.ViewData data = append(data, "1oko") tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data) } and it is working well in browser. The problem is not in index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped me.
I have solved my problem.
The problem was that i creating new local DB variable instead of updating DB global variable in NewDB func:

```
func NewDB(connStr string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    DB, err := sql.Open("mysql", connStr)
}
```

The working function should be

```
func NewDB(connStr string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    var err error
    DB, err = sql.Open("mysql", connStr)
}
```

Also find a good article about how to connect golang with dbs:
https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access
Hope it will help someone)